# How do i know in the preferenceactivity that something was changed?

Tags: android

I have few elements in my preferenceactivity and i would like to do some actions when a value is changed.

How can i get indication that a preference value was changed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use an [OnPreferenceChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.html). Get each preference you need from your PreferenceActivity, then set an OnPreferenceChangeListener to each one and do whatever you need to do with the Preference in onPreferenceChanged(..)

Answer (score 0):

There is an SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener spChanged = new

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {

    // your stuff here

};
```

Everything in a view generally has an onClickListener which can be overridden to make it do what you want to do.